# PHP Registration to MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, css, database, registration

I have a problem here..
Im currently building a website(blog) where I want people to be able to register. 
And I want that information to be sent to my MYSQL

This is some of the code:

```
<?php
$query="INSERT INTO Medlemmar(namn, epost)
VALUES("$_GET[namn]", "$_GET[epost]")";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql_pekare,$query))
  {
  die("Error: " . mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));
  }
echo "Du har lagt till kunden I databasen";
?>
```

But for some reason i get error on the "VALUES" part.. That im missing a syntax.. WTF am i missing?! Been stuck with this for 1+ hours.. Just had to turn here, usually a quick response! Thanks!

edit: "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE**"

Comment: Just have a look at the syntax highlighting and you'll see the problem yourself.

Comment: It only says its on the VALUES line, somewhere.. But I cant find it. Im starting to believe there is nothing wrong and something is bugging out..! haha

Comment: Keywords here would be "string concatenation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are syntax errors all over the place... This needs some work.

```
<?php 
  $query = "INSERT INTO Medlemmar(name, epost) VALUES(\"".$_GET['namn']."\", \"".$_GET['epost']."\")";
```

That should fix the query... You need to learn how to escape `\"` double quotes so they can be used in the actual query.

Comment: Thanks, this helped..
Tho now im struggling with another problem, But i appreciate it! ty!

Comment: No problem. There's a lot of little things that can trip you up when it comes to Php and MySQL, but keep trying and it'll eventually become second nature to you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
VALUES ('".$_GET[a]."', '".$_GET[b]."')
```

or ' and " exchanged.

Comment: Did not fix it, sorry.

Comment: You need to expand this: ... VALUES (''); to ... VALUES ('".$_GET[a]."'); or you need to prepare $get = $_GET[a]; and so on.

Comment: You can also try to use ` instead of '

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the single quotation marks around each value

Answer (score 0):

The way you're managing registration is extremely insecure. If you were to set the `namn` and `epost` value to a sql query (like `SELECT FIRST (username) FROM user_table`) then it would execute that as behalf of the original sql query.

> if you set username to SELECT FIRST (username) FROM user_table then it would return the first username in the user_table

To avoid this from happening you can use prepared statements which means that you specifically assign a sql query with a placeholder value and then you apply a value to the placeholder.
This would mean that you force the sql query to only execute what you've told it to do.

E.g. You want to JUST `INSERT` into a table and only do that and nothing else, no `SELECT` and no table `DROP` well in that case you create the prepared `INSERT` query with a placeholder value like this.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'database_user', 'database_user_password');
// Create the register statement for inserting.
// Question mark represent a placeholder for a value
$register = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users_table (username, password) values (?, ?)');

// Execute the register statement and give it values
// The values need to be parsed over in a array
$register->execute(array("test_user", "test_password"));
```

I'm not the best at explaining but if you want to understand what EXACTLY is going on here then [this](http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements/) is a pretty good article which explains it in more detail.